# WebSocket works on HTML file, but fails on hosted web page

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, webos, lg

I'm trying to use Websocket to remote-control a LG Smart TV (WebOS 4.0) by using [JSTVRemote](https://github.com/ar2rsawseen/JSTVRemote) JavaScript library.

It means the LG SmartTV is a websocket server, and my browser is a websocket client. The browser sends commands to control the TV, TV does the job (e.g. Volume Down) and send a response back to the client.

This library uses WebSocket to communicate with TV:

```
ws = new WebSocket( "wss://192.168.xxx.xxx:3000" ) ;

ws.onopen = function() {
    ws.onmessage = function( event ) {
        console.log( event ) ;
        alert('command successed!')
    }

    ws.onclose = function() {
        logUpdate( "Connection closed." ) ;
    }
}
ws.send(someCommand);
```

When I use it in a local HTML file (open it in browser with file://...), It works correctly. The `onmessage` event fires and returns the response from TV. Also, the TV does the job of command.

*Chrome, IE and Safari are OK

However, when I use it in a hosted web page (open the same HTML file with http://... or https://...), the `onmessage` event does not file and it reports an error with "WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.". Of course, the TV does not do the job of command.

*the connection establishing seems to succeed because the **new WebSocket()**, **ws.onopen()** and **ws.send()** are OK.

I have tried following web server, but they don't work.

- Apache
- IIS
- Web Server of QNAP(a NAS Server)

Does anyone know the reason of it?